# Debug running docker container in VS 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docker

How can I debug running docker container in Visual Studio 2017? 
I tried with Remote Debugger as per [post](https://www.richard-banks.org/2017/02/debug-net-in-windows-container.html). But, when i try to execute command:

`docker exec -it <id/name> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe" /nostatus /silent /noauth /anyuser /nosecuritywarn`,

i get an error:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\\\\Common7\\\\IDE\\\\Remote Debugger\\\\x64\\\\msvsmon.exe\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

Tried to run the Debugger manually and it starts without any problem.
I am using VS 2017 Community and i have downloaded proper remote tool for it.

I want to run remote debugger with running container and then to attach that process to VS debug.

Does anyone have an idea what am i missing?

Comment: Did you install the remote debugger in the docker container ?

Comment: I installed remote debugger manually on my machine...

Comment: This has to be installed inside the container and not on your machine. If you see the top of the article, they add it to the Dockerfile and then build that image and use it

Comment: Is there a way to install remote debugger directly inside running linux container, since i can not modify the image? I tried but i can hardly install .exe into linux container...

Comment: Are you using .NET core images or docker windows containers?

Comment: ASP.NET Core images for Linux

Comment: I think you picked wrong article for your need. Please look at http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2017/06/07/debugging-netcore-docker/ and https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio